# Should select queries ever take longer than 1 second?

Tags: mysql

I have select queries in my slow-log file that take 40-120 seconds.

When I consider something like a Google search, how fast that is, it makes me re-evaluate my entire database structure.

Since Google is literally searching billions of URLs in factions of a second, should I be worrying about 40 second queries?

```
# Query_time: 58.143590  Lock_time: 0.023085 Rows_sent: 3  Rows_examined: 1092421
use scrapers;
SET timestamp=1450286867;
SELECT * FROM `apps` WHERE dev_name = '' LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Google search does not really have much to do with this.  Yes lots of queries will take more than 1 second.  That one probably should not.

Comment: Only 3 rows returned, 1M (the whole table) scanned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be worried<sup>*</sup>. A simple query like this should be running in milliseconds and not examine a million rows.

My guess is that there are less than 10 rows that match the condition (evidence: `Rows_sent: 3`) and the lack of any index results in a full table scan (evidence: `Rows_examined: 1092421`). The `explain` output for the query would help us investigate if there is any other issue.

Good news is that a simple index on `(dev_name)` will probably solve the issue, for this query. Bad news is that you have to go through all the slow query, one by one, run `explain` on them, examine the tables and their indexes and either rewrite the queries or add appropriate indexes.

---

<sup>*: Of course, not because Google searches are fast. Any comparison between the super farms that a giant company uses and a single server is moot.</sup>

Comment: Unless there is blocking involved

Comment: @TomV in this case there is `Lock_time: 0.023085` so that does not seem to be the reason.